# Page.IsValid check internals?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0

I was wondering , how the `Page.IsValid` gets its value.

If a Page  has  validators  and a submit is occurring , 
how does the asp.net engine knows if the page was valid or not ?

- Does the result from client is kept in a hidden field ? ( I dont think so cause they doesnt generate any hidden fields). Also , I dont think it is kept in view state. cause Client side can add to a view state.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation is actually done at the server level. All the form values are posted back when you hit submit. And server side validators for each of the controls are called to check the validity of their user entered values.

Comment: This; there are both client- and server-side elements to the "inline" validators you put on a page; the client-side elements provide fast feedback, but if your user turns JavaScript off they aren't even run, so there is also a server-side component to protect your site's data integrity.

Comment: KeithS, I agree. I was just mentioning the part of the validation that Page.IsValid uses, but your further explanation does clear out things more.

Comment: Yes. It's not that surprising when you take to heart the axiom that you can *never* trust your client. Your client is in the hands of your end user, who may be an attacker. You cannot be sure the client code providing you with data is the code you wrote to do so, so it's safer to be pessimistic. Besides, most of the rules you can specify in a validator are very cheap; if you'd give the check in JavaScript to a client of unknown CPU power and expect it to be performant, how much more so will it be when run in compiled form on your backroom blade server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual code:

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        if (!this._validated)
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("IsValid_Cant_Be_Called"));
        }
        if (this._validators != null)
        {
            ValidatorCollection validators = this.Validators;
            int count = validators.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (!validators[i].IsValid)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It basically goes through all of the validators on the page and checks if they are all returning `IsValid = true`.  If any of them is invalid, it returns false.